# Server responses with IP Address instead of host name

Tags: dns, webserver, http, https

I have a Backend which is used as a REST API. When I make a request to the server (`GET https://subdomain.server.com/users/all`) I get this response from the server:

```
GET https://87.69.152.36/users/all
```

but I expect to get this response:

```
GET https://subdomain.server.com/users/all
```

Why is this happening? Can I configure it that I get the host name instead the IP in the response?

Answer (score 1):

If those `GET` actions really are responses from a server, then you need to look at how the server generates the reply. (There's no detail in your question that allows us to give you any advice on changing its response.)